# Constructing CFG from instructions where you have an OR

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

[image: cfg]

My question is: What tips or ideas do you have when you're gonna construct a CFG out of these instructions? If we only had 0 < i <= k, it'd be more straight forward if you ask me, but when we have an OR there, how should I approach it?

edit:

[image]

I just realized I could rewrite the language and then define the CFG
as S -> L1 | L2 whereas L1 and L2 is the union shown in the image

However, I still am not very sure if this would be the easiest way. Therefore, I'd still be happy if someone could show me an example of how to construct this CFG.

Comment: After looking around, I found similar threads and tips.

Comment: (You should use LaTeX instead of images.)

Comment: Oh, I noticed you were using mathjax or something but I had already made latex with an editor already.

Comment: Your solution is perfect and simple, as long as the constituent languages are indeed context-free.

Comment: I will make an attempt at it, and then come back with what I got as a result.

Comment: Hint: sometimes it helps rewriting $\{f(n,m) | n,m\in\mathbb{N}, n\leq m \}$ as $\{f(n,n+k) | n,k\in\mathbb{N} \}$